# Make multiple async calls in a single call in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I want to make multiple asynchronous calls in a single call without using a loop. For example, I'd like to pass a list of URIs and and retrieve all of them asynchronously in one call. Is this possible via C#?

Here's an [example in Java](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/httpasyncclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/nio/client/AsyncClientHttpExchangeFutureCallback.java) that does something similar to what I am looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get a list of tasks very easily - for example:

```
var tasks = uris.Select(async uri =>
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    return await client.GetStringAsync(uri)
                }
            })
            .ToList();
```

Note that if you want to use async/await, you'll need C# 5, not C# 4. You can still use .NET 4.0 if you use the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) Nuget package, but you *must* use a C# 5 compiler.

Comment: You might want to try reusing the `HttpClient` instance. I blieve it was desingned for that.